# How long communication timeout can be expected from a 802.11 infrastructure?

Tags: ieee-802.11

Imagine a client device ("station" in the wifi terminology) with an authenticated, living connection to a 802.11 infrastructure. The APs are expected to follow the relevant standards.

Then, the client device goes in suspension: all of its internal state remains, but it becomes incapable for any radio communication. Essentially, it is powered off.

Being powered on again, it has all what is needed to continue the 802.11 traffic as it wants to.

How long can the communication timeout last without a requirement of a new handshake?

Comment: About the context: the stations are embedded devices programmed by me, but I have no power over the APs. 802.11 connection handshakes last 5-10 seconds long. I want to spare these seconds so often as it is possible, by persisting the internal wifi state in memory.

Comment: WLAN timeout states the time a client session is allowed to exist from the WLAN data base entry perspective and the time can be different as configured. 
The client will remain associated until the client sends a disassociation packet by the standard or in your case the AP reboot.
The WLAN would then force the client to reauthenticate to insure security.

Comment: @ReshadZazai Thus, there is no time limit, at least not in the standard? Wow.